How does Icebreaking work?

I stumbled upon a diagram explaining how icebreaking works, in a book. It says that Q is the friction force acting on the hull and P is the force excerted by the pressure of the ice cube, on the hull. My question is since the pressure is caused by the normal force acting on the hull, how does it have two components R and F? Isn't it supposed to be perpendicular to the surface of the hull touching the ice cube and if it isn't how am I supposed to find the direction of a force like in this case?

I talk about this in my answer to Direction of the normal force. Ice is very slippery. The force of friction is so low that I often approximate it as $0$.
